# How to change the registry used by expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

With npm we change registry by using "npm config set registry "prefered registry".

How do we tell expo which registry to use?

(I need to tell expo to use http instead of https as https is not working through my proxy.)

Answer (score 0):

thats worked for me... i'm through enterprise proxy and I was needed to use `expo init`, but was not working...

My solution will permite "unanthorized responses", http instead https.

Expo version: 3.28.0

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiZOi.png)

How to Fix:

Correcting: `rejectUnauthorized : false` (not true linke image below)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOYun.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0H4v.png)

Comment: Please [do not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), post it as text instead

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it